# HTML Form Select Options are not hidden

Tags: php, html, forms

I am trying out HTML Forms now, and I've got a problem with this piece of Code

```
<select name="arrDay" size="31">
<?php
    for ($x = 1; $x <= 31; $x++) {
        echo '<option>' . $x . '</option>';
    }
?>
</select>
```

So there is a list with all this numbers, and I can select the single items, but it is not hidden in a dropdown panel, it is just written one below the other

Comment: Please be more elaborate like value of $x

Comment: As far as I know you option tag is not valid at all. You need some value in it. I can't test PHP right now but try to add a value to your options

Answer (score 1):

why use size in your code, remove it and if you want to select value then in option assign value

```
<select name="arrDay">
    <?php
    for ($x = 1; $x <= 31; $x++) {
         echo '<option value="'.$x.'">' . $x . '</option>';
    }
    ?>
</select>
```

if you want to set style to show more option at a time then use

```
<select name="arrDay" style="width: 70px; height: 200px">
    <?php
    for ($x = 1; $x <= 31; $x++) {
        echo '<option value="'.$x.'">' . $x . '</option>';
    }
    ?>
</select>
```

if you want to select multiple option then use multiple tag like this

```
<select name="arrDay" multiple>
    <?php
    for ($x = 1; $x <= 31; $x++) {
         echo '<option value="'.$x.'">' . $x . '</option>';
    }
    ?>
</select>
```

for more about multiple tag

https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_select_multiple.asp

Comment: Thx everyone! Thought it would be necessary to define the size of the list. Object thinking here x)

Comment: you already define option size in loop so no need that to use size tag

Comment: if you want to select value then check my update code

Answer (score 0):

remove size="31" from your cade

```
<select name="arrDay">
                <?php
                    for ($x = 1; $x <= 31; $x++) {
                        echo '<option>' . $x . '</option>';
                    }
                ?>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

The size attribute expands the dropdown to show x items on screen, and thus provides an option to use it as listbox instead of drop down.

[Read this article.](http://html.com/attributes/select-size/)